# Assert that a function gets called

Tags: php, phpunit

When testing with phpunit, I want to assert a function call:

Given a Class:

```
Class TimeWrapper {
  public function time() {
    return time();
  }
}
```

And Its unittest:

```
Class TimeWrapperTest extends PHPUnit_FrameworkTestCase {
  public function testTime() {
    //Pseudocode as example of a possible solution:
    $this->assertCallsFunction("time");
  }
}
```

I am specifically looking for a way to test calling of global functions.

FWIW: with rspec, I use [Message Expectations](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames). I am looking to achieve something similar, or exactly similar in PHPUnit.

Comment: Have you read the [Chapter about Test Doubles](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)?

Comment: Yes. But AFAIK they do not allow you to stub global functions or builtin fuctions. The SUT is a Drupal addon. Drupal is a CMS that has all its APIs in global space: e.g. cache_get() my DrupalWrapper calls that function, and I am not interested in including Drupal, nor in testing its entire stack. Hence I want to stub "cache_get()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to verify that `TimeWrapper` calls the built-in PHP function `time`, you'll need to use the [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension. This will allow you to replace the built-in function with your own version that will record the call. You'll need to enable the `runkit.internal_override` setting in `php.ini` to allow you to rename internal functions.

```
class TimeWrapperTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    static $calledTime;

    function setUp() {
        self::$calledTime = false;
    }

    function testTimeGetsCalled() {
        $fixture = new TimeWrapper;
        try {
            runkit_function_rename('time', 'old_time');
            runkit_function_rename('new_time', 'time');
            $time = $fixture->time();
            self::assertTrue('Called time()', $calledTime);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // PHP lacks finally, but must make sure to revert time() for other test
        }
        runkit_function_rename('time', 'new_time');
        runkit_function_rename('old_time', 'time');
        if ($e) throw $e;
    }
}

function new_time() {
    TimeWrapperTest::$calledTime = true;
    return old_time();
}
```

If you cannot use the extension or just want to avoid that kind of trickery, you could modify `TimeWrapper` to allow you to override the function that gets called at runtime.

```
class TimeWrapper {
    private $function;

    public function __construct($function = 'time') {
        $this->function = $function;
    }

    public function time() {
        return call_user_func($this->function);
    }
}
```

Use the test case above without the calls to `runkit_function_rename` and pass `new_time` to the `TimeWrapper` constructor. The downside here is that you'll pay a (probably tiny) performance penalty in production on each call to `TimeWrapper::time`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's something already done for that purpose.

But if you're trying to implement it yourself, you could take a look at [xdebug code coverage](http://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage)